# Validating the elements of an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I have a input array of elements that is passed to the controller. So far I have checked that the data is there, is of "array" type and has at least 1 element.

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [ 'option' => 'required|array|min:1' ]);
```

But now I would like to make sure that all the elements within the array are not either emtpy (for instance a string `""` or empty space `"    "`. I can not anticipate how many elements the array will have.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom validation rule [Here are the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

**Something like this:**

```
Validator::extend('array_not_whitespace', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    foreach($value as $entry)
    {
        if (strlen(trim($entry)) == 0)
           return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

**with**

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [ 'option' => 'required|array_not_whitespace|min:1' ]);
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need to check for `strlen` without `trim`. `strlen(trim($entry)) == 0` will cover everything.